Prevent minimization when clicking an app on the taskbar
I am using remote desktop and there is sometimes a lot of delay.
On the taskbar, If I click on the icon for an app, the app is brought to the the front if it isn't already in front.  If it is, then it is minimized.  I can click repeatedly to toggle between these two states
When there is a lot of delay, I can't always tell when my last click will eventually bring the app to the front or minimize it.  I prefer to eliminate the minimization behaviour.  So if I click on an icon in the taskbar, I want the app to be brought to the front.  If it is already in front, then I want it to stay in front.
Is there a native setting by which this can be accomplished? By "native", I mean a setting in Windows itself rather than a 3rd party tool.  I don't mean the default behaviour (which is what I'm trying to avoid).
There is Taskbar Tweaker, but I can install very little on my remote machines.

No, there is not a "native" solution. The native behavior is that clicking an icon on the taskbar toggles, as you've observed.

I clarified what I mean by "native".

Exactly, there is no way to natively disable minimizing windows by clicking them in the task bar. I would recommend keyboard alternatives like Alt+Tab, or for remote desktop, Alt(and hold)+pgUp  > select window. In fullscreen rdp, you can use the windows shortcuts like Win+[number row key] to open the matching window (Win+1=leftmost taskbar icon), which can be more consistent than mouse clicks in a low-quality connection

I use Alt+Tab, but that's slow for a slow RDP connection.  Alt+pgUp doesn't work, but I have an unusual setup where I use an RDP-like connection (layered with extra security by a 3rd part), and from the remote machine, an RDP connection to a 3rd machine. The final option Win+numer row key works, but may be hard to get used to because there are pinned icons on the taskbar that I don't control, so counting taskbar items can distract from the task at hand (and pinned items vary between machines). My best bet is to live with the minimization when clicking on the taskbar. Thanks!
